# Managing issues across multiple github repositories

Tags: github, project-management

I am managing issues and projects in multiple GitHub repositories within a GitHub organization. Each repository has its own project and project board. However, I'm looking for a tool or product to get an overview of multiple projects/repositories in one view.

In addition, it would be nice to be able to make changes in this overview that is applied to the GitHub issue/project.

I´ve found a product CodeTree (https://codetree.com/guides/managing-issues-across-multiple-github-repositories) which seems to target this task/issue. However, I would like to reach out and see if there are alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out ZenHub is a great alternative, doing the exact thing I'm looking for. CodeTree was a bit unstable in my opinion.

UPDATE 2021-12-16: GitHub is rolling out this feature as a beta version right now. See: https://docs.github.com/en/issues/trying-out-the-new-projects-experience

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jira for project management and issue tracking. It has a GitHub integration, enabling you to attach a branch or a PR to an issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).